# How to display current class and function running in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, metadata, xcode6

I want to return the class and function for debugging purposes.  In Objective-C I would use the following, how would I do the same in Swift?

Obective-C

```
if (debug==1) {
    NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class,NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
```

Swift

```
if debug==1 {
    println("Running: ", self ,__FUNCTION__)
}
```

In swift, this would return something like this:

```
(Running: , <myTeamManager.PlayerInformationTableViewController: 0x7fa18bd31680>, viewDidLoad())
```

but I only want `PlayerInformationTableViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reflect(self).summary.pathExtension
```